# how to clear github auto login in window git bash?

Tags: git, window

I use window 7.
I push to github remote repo on window git bash.
window require login github to me, so I type github Id and password. 
and I complete push. but next time, in push command, Window auto login to github. I don't want auto login to github. How do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```